# Running AWS Codebuild locally without buildspec.yml but CDK

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codebuild, cicd

I am using this [template as a basis for my Serverless backend](https://github.com/fourTheorem/slic-starter#cicd) I've tried deploying it but had several failures, which resulted in me getting billed. Now to avoid further costs I am trying to run [CodeBuild locally](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/use-codebuild-agent.html), now this requires buildspec.yml file to be present, but in the template, everything is done with the CDK. Everything for the Codebuild/ Pipeline is in the [CICD folder](https://github.com/fourTheorem/slic-starter/tree/master/cicd) and I am unsure how to run this. I've tried searching but every example requires the buildspec file.

This is the result of `aws codebuild batch-get-projects --names <project_name> | jq '.projects[0].source.buildspec' -r` command with name being SLICPipelineSource

```
aws codebuild batch-get-projects --names SLICPipelineSource | jq '.projects[0].source.buildspec' -r
{
  "version": "0.2",
  "phases": {
    "install": {
      "runtime-versions": {
        "nodejs": 12,
        "python": 3.8
      },
      "commands": [
        "npm install"
      ]
    },
    "build": {
      "commands": [
        "bash ./build-scripts/source-kickoff.sh https://github.com/<ACCOUNT>/Project.git $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION"
      ]
    }
  },
  "artifacts": {
    "files": "**/*"
  }
}
```

[image]

These are [basically build scripts](https://github.com/fourTheorem/slic-starter/tree/master/build-scripts)

Comment: You say `codespec.yml` - do you mean `buildspec.yml`?

Comment: @Hcaertnit yes sorry, codespec was in my head the whole time while writing this...

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I think aws-cdk is only for provissioning the infrastructure and pipelines and not building the images

Comment: @Debdut it can actually do a lot, e.g. [build webapps using custom commands](https://github.com/davidtucker/ps-serverless-app/blob/e44782b565da447412bcdce969659fd52c429d45/infrastructure/lib/core/webapp.ts#L61-L70), so I wouldn't be surprised if it _can_ do you what you're saying.

Comment: @Nikola try this to see your buildspec: `aws codebuild batch-get-projects --names <project_name> | jq '.projects[0].source.buildspec' -r`.  (It won't work if your buildspec is in a file in the repository)

Comment: @Hcaertnit added it as an edit, it shows the command its running but no build file

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to copy/paste that outputed JSON directly into a file called `buildspec.yml` and put it in your repository.  Since YAML is actually a superset of JSON, all JSON is valid YAML so it should work.